# Spitting flac files in linux

Tags: linux, flac, cue

I have been trying to split a large flac file using the cue file and shntool. I am getting the error "error: m:ss.ff format can only be used with CD-quality files". 
I have tried everything I have read on google to solve this with no joy. I have quite a few of these album length files that come in a large flac file with cue file and can't split them. I would like to do this without having to resort to wine or virtualbox. Also I have seen mention of cuetools for linux but have been unable to find it except for ubuntu and I don't use ubuntu, any help there would be appreciated too.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest why I have found so far is to use mp3splt, which I found after exhaustive searching. It also splits flac files.

flacsplt -a -c cuefile.cue -d /directory/to/send/file flacfilename.flac

there is also a gtk interface for people who like that sort of thing.  mp3splt-gtk